# Correct database structure for a results table in a 'fantasy football' database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, ddl

In this scenario I have: players, fantasy football leagues (communities), and results.

1 user can be part of many fantasy leagues.

I have a current structure of:

```
create table players (id int, email, display_name)
create table communities (id int, name, password, admin_email)
create table community_players (community_id, player_id)
```

I now need to create a results table for each community. I was thinking:

```
create table results (player1_id, player1_points, player1_goals_scored, player2_id, player2_points, player2_goals_scored, date, community_id)
```

My concern is this table will end up being huge.  And so when I go to run queries on it for stats (i.e, who beat who, numbers of goals scored, goals conceded, etc) it will end up incredibly slow.

My thoughts is:

Should I create a results table 'on-the-fly' for every Community that is created?

```
create table results_community_name (player1_id, player1_points, player1_goals_scored, player2_id, player2_points, player2_goals_scored, date, community_id)
```

Comment: Creating a table for each record in another table is a famously bad idea.  What's actually wrong with the structure you have now?  What measurements or estimates do you have regarding its performance and scalability?

Comment: I wasn't looking to create a table for each record in another table, just in the database - or is that what you mean?

I don't have any measurements or estimates other than if I use just the one table I estimate it may querying around 100,000 records when pulling out stats such as goals scored.

Comment: `"create a results table 'on-the-fly' for every Community"` - Does this not imply that you would create a table for each record in the `communities` table?  As for the record count, 100,000 records in a table of nothing buts integers is a pretty low volume of data.

Comment: 100,000 records is peanuts. Wait until you grow to 100 times that size. Then start worrying about performance.

Comment: David - yes it does.  Sorry, I thought you meant something different. I'm still getting my head around database structures!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databases are built for storing rows. **Lots** of rows. With proper indexing and maintenance, you should never really experience a problem with performance. On the other hand, creating a table per community will not only complicate your code, but would quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

If performance really becomes an issue, you should look into MySQL's [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html). Essentially, it creates N physical tables hidden behind one logical table, which is kind of like your idea of creating a table per community, but in a much easier way to manage.

Comment: Thanks, I think after yours and Davids comments i will go with the single results table

Comment: Does the results_table need it's own 'id' column?